# Quadratic Programming and Lasso

Tags: regression, lasso, quadratic-form

I'm trying to perform a lasso regression, which has following form:

Minimize $w$ in $(Y - Xw)'(Y - Xw) + \lambda  \;|w|_1$

Given a $\lambda$, I was advised to find the optimal $w$ with the help of quadratic programming, which takes the following form:

Minimize $x$ in $\frac{1}{2}  x'Qx + c'x$, subject to $Ax \le b.$

Now I realize that the $\lambda$ term should be transformed into the constraint term $Ax \le b$, which is rather straightforward. However, I somehow just don't see how I could transfer the first term of the first equation into the first term of the second. I couldn't find much about it on the net, so I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keeping in mind that we're working with $w$ as the '$x$' variable in the standard form, expand $(Y - Xw)'(Y - Xw)$ and collect terms in $w'\, [\,_{^{^\text{something}}}]\,w$ and in $w'$ and $w$, and constants.

Explain why you can ignore the constants.

Explain why you can combine the $w'$ and $w$ terms.

---

As BananaCode has by now figured out with some leading along the path, you can either write $Q=2X'X$ and $c=-2X'Y$ *or* more simply, you could just write $Q=X'X$ and $c=-X'Y$ (since $f(x)$ and $kf(x)$ have the same argmin for any $k>0$).

Comment: The constants can be ignored, because if x_ is the minimum to f(x), then x_ + c is the minimum of f(x) + c, hence we can ignore the constant c. I'll edit my question to show where I got stuck.

Comment: BananaCode your explanation has several flaws. If by "is the minimum to $f(x)$" you mean "is the argument at which $f(x)$ is minimized", you say something like "$x^*$ is the $\text{argmin}$ of $f$". But your conclusion there is wrong. If you add $c$ to $f$, you don't add $c$ to the argmin.

Comment: See where I wrote $w'\, [\,\text{something}]\,w$ in my answer?  What's the *something* you now have between the $w'$ and the $w$ at the bottom of your question??

Comment: Yes, I meant $x*$ is the $argmin$ of $f$. Could you give an example where my conclusion is wrong?
The $[something]$ is the $Q$ matrix I'm trying to form. If I expand $w'(X'Xw - X'Y)$ I get $w'X'Xw - w'X'Y$. The first part would represent the form of the $Q$ matrix, however I can't get rid of the second term $-w'X'Y$.

Comment: An example: the argmin of $x^2$ is at 0. The argmin of $x^2+\sqrt{\pi}$ is still at 0, not $\sqrt{\pi}$. You don't 'get rid of' the other term. Re-read my answer, which already discussed how to deal with that term.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. I actually meant that, and have no idea why I wrote that mistake. Of course, you are right.

Comment: Do you follow what I was getting at with $w'$ in the second part of the comment?

Comment: No, I apologize but I can't see how to combine the $w'$ and $w$ terms.

Comment: you know that if $a$ is a vector of the same dimension as $w$ that $a'w$ is a scalar, right?

Comment: Try an example. Consider $w=(w_1,w_2)'$ and $a=(1,2)$. Compute $w'a$. Compute $a'w$. ... what do you notice? Does that generalize?

Comment: I think I might have figured it out:
$w'X'Xw - w'X'Y - Y'Xw = w'X'Xw - (X'Y)'w - Y'Xw = w'X'Xw - ((X'Y)' - Y'X)w$
Is this correct?

Comment: Continuing on:

$ ... = w'X'Xw - (Y'X - Y'X)w = w'X'Xw$

Did I derive this correctly?

Comment: No, that's not quite correct. You have the right general idea, but you mucked up one of the signs along the way. If you do it right, the term in $w$ doesn't cancel out.

Comment: Ah yeah, I think I see the error, would've been strange if the answer did not depend on Y: $w'X'Xw - Y'Xw - Y'Xw = w'X'Xw - 2Y'Xw$. Now, that should be correct!

Comment: Now summarized into the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it! 2 AM here, time for bed, heh.

Comment: Just a question, what would be A? b I think is just the value of lambda, correct?

Comment: @AD.Net The constraints are mostly covered in the other answer.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to add how to solve transforming the constraints $\sum |w_i| \le s$ into a usable form for quadratic programming, as it is not quite as straightforward as I thought. It's not possible to find a real matrix $A$ such that $Aw \le s \leftrightarrow \sum |w_i| \le s$.

The approach I used was to split the elements $w_i$ of vector $w$ into $w_i^+$ and $w_i^-$, so that $w_i = w_i^+ - w_i^-$. If $w_i \ge 0$, you have $w_i^+ = w_i$ and $w_i^- = 0$, else you have $w_i^- = |w_i|$ and $w_i^+ = 0$. Or in more mathematical terms, $w_i^+ = \frac{|w_i| + w_i}{2} $ and $w_i^- = \frac{|w_i| - w_i}{2}.$ Both $w_i^-$ and $w_i^+$ are non-negative numbers. The idea behind splitting the numbers up is that you now have $|w_i| = w_i^+ + w_i^-$, effectively getting rid of the absolute values.

The function to optimize turns into: $\frac{1}{2}(w^+ - w^-)^TQ(w^+ - w^-) + c^T(w^+ - w^-)$, subject to 
$ w_i^+ + w_i^- \le s, \\ w_i^+,w_i^- \ge 0$

Where $Q$ and $c$ are given as stated above by Glen_b

This needs to be transformed into a usable form, i.e we need one vector. This is done in the following way:

$ \frac{1}{2} \bigg[ \begin{array}{c} w^+ \\ w^- \end{array} \bigg]^T \bigg[ \begin{array}{cc} Q & -Q \\ -Q & Q  \end{array} \bigg] \bigg[ \begin{array}{c} w^+ \\ w^- \end{array}\bigg] + \big[ \begin{array}{cc} c^T & -c^T \end{array} \big] \bigg[ \begin{array}{c} w^+ \\ w^- \end{array}\bigg]$

subject to

$\bigg[ \begin{array}{cc} I_D & I_D \\ -I_{2D} \end{array} \bigg]\bigg[ \begin{array}{c} w^+ \\ w^- \end{array}\bigg] \le \bigg[ \begin{array}{c} s_D \\ 0_{2D} \end{array}\bigg]$

Where $I_D$ is the $D$-dimensional unit matrix, $s_D$ a $D$-dimensional vector consisting only of the value $s$ and $0_D$ a $2*D$-dimensional zero vector. The first half ensures $|w_i| = w_i^+ + w_i^- \le s$, the second $w_i^+,w_i^- \ge 0$ Now it's in a usable form to use quadratic programming to search for $w^+$ and $w^-$, given $s$. Once that is done, your optimal parameter with respect to $s$ is $w = w^+ - w^-$.

Source and further reading: [Solving quadratic programming problem with linear constraints containing absolute values](http://www.aei.tuke.sk/papers/2012/3/02_Bu%C5%A1a.pdf)

Comment: Suppose that we've found an optimal $2D$-dimensional vector $(w^+, w^-)$. What ensures that $w^+$ and $w^-$ are actually the positive parts and negative parts of some vector $w$, i.e. their $0$ entry positions match up?

Comment: Matrix and vector in final expression can be more simple, and actually more correct. Instead of [Id Id] [w+ w−]' ≤  Sd you could put simply [1 1 .... 1][w+ w-]' ≤  s. This is literally equivalent to ∑|wi| = ∑(wi+ + wi−) ≤ s.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping in long after the initial discussion here, but following [a question on a QP-related forum](https://github.com/qpsolvers/qpsolvers/discussions/223#discussioncomment-7873692), I wrote the following note on [Lasso regularization in quadratic programming](https://scaron.info/blog/lasso-regularization-in-quadratic-programming.html). It also introduces additional variables, but rather than separating $w_i = w_i^+ - w_i^-$ (which is an alternative I haven't tried) it introduces $z_i$ such that

- $+w_i \leq z_i$
- $-w_i \leq z_i$

Then making sure at least one of the two inequalities in each such pair is tight by adding the usual $\lambda \| w \|_1 = \lambda z$ to the objective function.